Identifying all columns shared in common by a set of files and then vertically stack them
I have these data frames in R:
abc_1 <- data.frame(col1 = 1:5, col2 = 6:10, col3 = 11:15)
abc_2 <- data.frame(col1 = 21:25, col2 = 26:30, col4 = 31:35)
abc_3 <- data.frame(col1 = 41:45, col2 = 46:50, col5 = 51:55)
def_1 <- data.frame(col1 = 61:65, col2 = 66:70, col6 = 71:75)

For all data frames starting with "abc_", I want to identify the set of columns shared in common with all files, and then rbind them together.
I tried to do this the long way:
all_objects <- ls()

abc_objects <- all_objects[grep("^abc", all_objects)]

common_cols <- Reduce(intersect, lapply(abc_objects, function(x) colnames(get(x))))

combined_df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(abc_objects, function(x) {
  df <- get(x)
  df[, common_cols, drop = FALSE]
}))

Is there a more direct way to do this?

Staying close to your approach, you can do
abc_1 <- data.frame(col1 = 1:5, col2 = 6:10, col3 = 11:15)
abc_2 <- data.frame(col1 = 21:25, col2 = 26:30, col4 = 31:35)
abc_3 <- data.frame(col1 = 41:45, col2 = 46:50, col5 = 51:55)
def_1 <- data.frame(col1 = 61:65, col2 = 66:70, col6 = 71:75)

i = mget(ls(pattern="abc_")) # "^([a-z]){3}_" for all
do.call("rbind", lapply(i, "[", Reduce(intersect, lapply(i, names))))

giving
        col1 col2
abc_1.1    1    6
abc_1.2    2    7
abc_1.3    3    8
abc_1.4    4    9
abc_1.5    5   10
abc_2.1   21   26
abc_2.2   22   27
abc_2.3   23   28
abc_2.4   24   29
abc_2.5   25   30
abc_3.1   41   46
abc_3.2   42   47
abc_3.3   43   48
abc_3.4   44   49
abc_3.5   45   50

Notice that, those row names can be deleted with an additional |> `row.names<-`(NULL).

Here is an alternative. I'd start by creating a list of the dataframes, which can then be bound (do.call(rbind... won't work with the different column names).
library(dplyr)

abc_objects <- do.call("list", mget(grep("^abc", names(.GlobalEnv), value = TRUE)))

bind_rows(abc_objects) |>
  select(where(~ !any(is.na(.))))
#>    col1 col2
#> 1     1    6
#> 2     2    7
#> 3     3    8
#> 4     4    9
#> 5     5   10
#> 6    21   26
#> 7    22   27
#> 8    23   28
#> 9    24   29
#> 10   25   30
#> 11   41   46
#> 12   42   47
#> 13   43   48
#> 14   44   49
#> 15   45   50


This solution is based on the assumption that the joint columns don‘t contain any NA‘s, which might or might not fit to TO‘s real data.
